# Function that will read the data from a column and generate the missing rows dynamically

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-programming

i have a function that return missing documentno from a table but lenght of left part of data in column documentno is passed manually and right part has some ambiguities.
Now i want a function that will read the data from a column (documentno) and return the missing documentno dynamically.

my query :

```
CREATE TABLE c_order (
  "order_id" VARCHAR(22),
  "documentno" VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO c_order
  ("order_id", "documentno")
VALUES
  ('100001120', 'AGB/2021/02050'),
  ('100001124' ,'AGB/2021/02055'),
  ('100001120', 'PROFS/2021/02056'),
  ('100001124' ,'PROF/2021/02060'),
  ('100001125' ,'PROF/2021/02065'),
  ('100001120', 'PROFS/2020/02050_A'),
  ('100001124' ,'PROFS/2020/02055_A'),
  ('100001120', 'PROFS/2021/02056'),
  ('100001124' ,'PROFSS/2021/0206010'),
  ('100001125' ,'PROFSS/2021/0206020')

with cte as (
  select left(documentno,13) lpart, 
         regexp_replace(split_part(documentno, '/', 3), '[^0-9]', '', 'g')::int as num
  from c_order
), minmax as (
  select lpart, min(num) minpart, max(num) maxpart
  from cte
  group by lpart
)
select lpart||t.doc_no as missing_doc_no
from minmax m
  cross join generate_series(minpart, maxpart) as t(doc_no) 
  where not exists (select * 
                  from c_order c
                  where regexp_replace(split_part(c.documentno, '/', 3), '[^0-9]', '', 'g')::int = t.doc_no)
```

my fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0d3a6a647c6ef2a9063c7f3289446998

How can I do that?

Comment: @Ken White do you have any approch?

Comment: @Lennart do you have any approch?

Comment: @eshirvana do you have any approch

Comment: Please provide expected output.

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis

AGB/2021/02051----------------not AGB/2021/02052051
AGB/2021/02052----------------not AGB/2021/02052052
AGB/2021/02053----------------not AGB/2021/02053
AGB/2021/02054----------------not AGB/2021/02054
PROFSS/2021/0206011
PROFSS/2021/0206012
PROFSS/2021/0206013
PROFSS/2021/0206014
PROFSS/2021/0206015
PROFSS/2021/0206016
PROFSS/2021/0206017
PROFSS/2021/0206018
PROFSS/2021/0206019
PROFS/2020/02051
PROFS/2020/02052
PROFS/2020/02053
PROFS/2020/02054
PROF/2021/02061
PROF/2021/02062
PROF/2021/02063
PROF/2021/02064

---Right part not generate good datas,

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis do you have any approch?  see : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0d3a6a647c6ef2a9063c7f3289446998

Comment: Please see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=24ba8483f263a22a3be47ccf862ec4c4  Hope it works for you

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis some rows not generate see : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2c3bb5916ad5795c489f62f70538fbe9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't write the whole solution since you already got it right, but here is how to get the  last numeric part dynamically using regular expression :

```
select
    substring(documentno, '\w*\/\d*\/') constantpart ,
    max(substring(regexp_replace(documentno, '\w*\/\d*\/', '') from '\d*'))::int Maxnumericpart,
    min(substring(regexp_replace(documentno, '\w*\/\d*\/', '') from '\d*'))::int Minnumericpart
from c_order co 
group by constantpart
```

ok , here is the full solutions:

```
select tt.constantpart || LPAD(t.doc_no::text,ll,'0') missingdocumentNo
from 
(select
    substring(documentno, '\w*\/\d*\/') constantpart ,
    max(substring(regexp_replace(documentno, '\w*\/\d*\/', '') from '\d*'))::int Maxnumericpart,
    min(substring(regexp_replace(documentno, '\w*\/\d*\/', '') from '\d*'))::int Minnumericpart,
    length(min(substring(regexp_replace(documentno, '\w*\/\d*\/', '') from '\d*'))) ll
from c_order co 
group by constantpart
) tt
cross join generate_series(Minnumericpart, Maxnumericpart) as t(doc_no) 
where not exists (
        select 1
        from c_order co2 
        where substring(co2.documentno, '\w*\/\d*\/\d*') = tt.constantpart || LPAD(t.doc_no::text,ll,'0')
    )
order by missingdocumentNo;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a9a2a8b4e9cc3dc3c4fa4c8b118d6ea2)*

Comment: it is possible to add this here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6ae0078ff6b8c3ce285ea67fe68eb8bc

Comment: in my local bd, that return  ERROR: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Comment: as you see it works in dbfiddle ( link inside solution) , so I don't know how to help you with that , unless  you have some data in your table that they don't have any number part

Comment: how can i do to add leading zero?

Comment: @FranckWhite you  could google it but see my updated answer ;)